# How can one achieve incredible chakra such as that of the Third Raikage or Kisame?

Tags: naruto

Kisame was known as tailed beast without tails. This is because he had an incredible amount of chakra, so much that Samehada had an affection toward him.

A's father, the Third Raikage, could even combat the Hachibi all alone!
What is the source of such an amount of chakra? Is it hereditary? Or won by practice? Or just by birth?

Might Guy, the Green Beast of Konoha, opened the 8 Gates to surpass Kisame, but doing this takes a risk on his life. So it is certainly not the manipulation of chakra points, since neither the Third Raikage nor Kisame seem to be risking their lives to get such an amount of chakra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are times where a genius is born. It doesn't have to be in raw chakra, but in skill, brains, willpower, etc.

Itachi for example is considered a genius, a fast learner, combat analyst and very powerful.
Madara is a genius. Awakening the Mangekyo, having power many shinobi feared.
A's father can also be considered a genius. Steel skin and iron blood, along with the incredible chakra and durability to match that of the Eight Tails.

Kisame is a slightly different case. He's definitely fearsome strong, but his gigantic chakra reservoirs actually came from his sword, Samehade, which has the ability to consume the chakra of the victims it hits.

Comment: According to Choujurou (chapter 468, page 10) Kisame has a high level of chakra even without Samehada. However, the combination of him and the sword make an extremely larger amount of chakra available to him. And he also seems to be able to absorb chakra even without Samehada (possibly because he is in direct contact with water), as shown in chapter 506, page 5.

Comment: I don't think Sasuke qualifies as a genius.  Itachi, however, does!

Comment: @Itachi, situations, circumstances and consequences made him mad, otherwise he was potentially a great shinobi and he has always been a keen and quick learner.. also possessed very good plotting against enemies he had been fighting.. ofcourse itachi as elder brother possessed more knowledge than him, Sasuke could have been genius..

Comment: @Sai: He was never mad, it was all part of the act.

Comment: @itachi technically, everry main character classifies as genius. average Ninja are genin, maybe chunnin. The konoha 12 are all roughly at least jonin, with several being above that. Sasuke with Mangekyou was Kage level. It should be that way, since most are the directly in line to inherit the Head of the clan position, or at least are children of the head of the clan, they are meant to as adults be the strongest in their clans, at least jonin.

Answer (score 4):

All people are different, and all sihnobi are different. We know that some people are talented in poetry, and some in math. Some have good memory, some are stronger than others. How do they "achieve" this? Well, they usually don't. They just have it.

The same thing applies to shinobi too. Some are naturally better in genjitsu, some in ninjitsu. Some have Kekkei Genkai, some have more chakra than others. Of course, when one trains, he further increases his ability, and even if someone is not really good with genjitsu, he can work hard to improve, much like anyone can, for example, attend a music class and learn to play an instrument.

So yes, if you don't count any "special stuff" such as Kisame's sword, I would say that it's something they have from birth.

Comment: Thank you @SingerOfTheFall, you always provide notable answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I think chakra is actually inherited directly from the parents and can be honed via training.
As we know, Naruto has immense amount of chakra, more than even a regular jounin level shinobi (Kakashi told that Naruto has 4 times more chakra than himself without counting the chakra of the nine tails), since his childhood and could perform forbidden Multi shadow clone jutsu which would be otherwise impossible unless one has huge chakra at his disposal.
So, there is higher possibility that Third Raikage and Kisame's parents had incredible amount of chakra.

Comment: I don't think you can inherit chakra reserves

Comment: Either you have to save it as Tsunade and Sakura does or you have to have it in you. I do not see any other way around. And FYI, tailed beast, Samehada and other ninja tools are excluded.

Answer (score 0):

It is specifically stated that a shinobi can increase his or her chakra volume via training. It is stated in the manga, anime and databooks that Chakra is created when two other forms of energy, known collectively as one's "stamina", are moulded together. Physical energy (身体エネルギー, shintai enerugī) is collected from each and every one of the body's cells and can be increased through training, stimulants, and exercise. Spiritual energy (精神エネルギー, seishin enerugī, English TV: Mental Energy) is derived from the mind's consciousness and can be increased through studying, meditation, and experience. These two energies becoming more powerful will in turn make the created chakra more powerful. Therefore, practising a technique repeatedly will build up experience, increasing one's spiritual energy, and thus allowing more chakra to be created.

so any character who has large chakra reserves developed it by either increasing the physical or spiritual energy or both. through physical training such as running, push ups etc etc or doing mental training such as studying, reading, meditating etc etc.

on top of that another important factor is chakra control which is important because all though its possible to maximize the amount of chakra a shinobi has. there are still some limitations based on genetics.  as such this is why someone like kakashi has average levels of chakra volume. but i also believe that its possible to break the limit to a degree. one such way is to seal chakra away for later use. this will grant you a higher level of standing chakra volume and in turn it will allow you to train harder and develop chakra beyond the limits of your genetics IE tsunade was born with chakra of a high calbre and volume because she is senju/uzumaki. but the seal on her fourhead clearly allows for even greater chakra volumes